# Restrict autoincrement on MYSQL when insert duplicate record

Tags: php, mysql

When I go to insert duplicate value and ignore that value to insert in column 'tagName' then id is increasing automaitcally but I do not need to jump the ID's Here I have is with a table with two columns -- `INNODB - ID(autoincrement), tagName(unique varchar)`

when doing `INSERT IGNORE INTO tablename SET tagName="something"` the autoincrement Id value increases even if the insert was ignored.

for example I'm displaying 3 rows but bad IDs.

```
ID   tagName
1    test
8    test111
29   test2222
```

I do not want to use the sub queries

Thanks

Comment: Ignore is for ignoring errors not operations and under normal circumstances you'd basically never use it. See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: well, why does it bother you?

Comment: you can use php to restrict to run the insert query on duplicate record.

Comment: I do not want to use php code

Comment: Suppose I have a billions of records then php loops and sub queries will not better for that So only need in mysql without using sub queries and php

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question right, then what you're asking is if you can stop autoincrement incrementing if you tried to insert a row and the insertion failed.

The behaviour you're observing is a deliberate design choice that almost all major databases (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc) also do, for the reason that autoincrementing columns are almost always used to give a new row a unique ID, and if you attempt to insert a row then the next available value is assigned to it from the autoincrement which then increments itself.

If the insertion failed but another one that occurs at almost the same time succeeds then that new row's ID is already fixed.  It's considered very bad practice to change a row's ID once it's been established, especially in a database that makes use of foreign keys, therefore simply allowing a gap in the numbering to exist is a better approach than to attempt to update all the rows that may have been inserted in the time since the insert failure occurred, especially as yet more new rows may be in the process of being inserted while you're updating all those rows.  There's going to be a window where the database is in an inconsistent state.

In short, there's no good reason for rolling back an autoincrement value after a failed insert (other than OCD) and plenty of good reasons for not rolling it back.

Comment: Simple thing I want to stop insert duplicate record . I i use the unique key then it sure to ignore the duplicate value but auto increment jump to next

Comment: When you insert the autoincrement always increments (that's what autoincrement means!).  You could try querying the database to see if a record of the type you're about to insert already exists and skip the insertion if it does, but if the database is busy enough you could still get the odd collision anyway.

Comment: Auto increment means auto increment IDs  "problem is that when i insert record and if this record also exist in the column then i want to skit the insertion with out ID increment "

Comment: Then you have to check the record *before* you attempt to insert or add unique definitions to some of your other columns.